# Regex (.NET) for strings ending with FIRST OCCURENCE of "xyz"

Tags: .net, regex

I need a regex that matches first "xyz" and all characters that come before. For example, for
"abxyzcdxyz" it should match "abxyz". I was trying with pattern ".*xyz", but it matches the entire string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try non-greedy matching:

```
.*?xyz
```

`*?` is a non-greedy quantifier, i.e. it matches zero or more occurrences, but as few as possible.

Comment: Isn't the wild card for end-of-string missing in this expression?

Comment: @divo: no, the *substring match* should end on `xyz`, not the whole string.